# How can I fix this error " AnyObject? is not convertible to 'string'"?

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to connect the database by using external databases with an API on my application, I get an error in `loadPostsfunction`.

Error:

> AnyObject is not convertible to String

Code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        service = PostService()
        service.getPosts(){
            (response) in
            self.loadPosts(response["posts"]! as! NSArray)
        }
    }
    /////////////////// In here ///////////////////////
    func loadPosts(posts:NSArray) {
        for post in posts {
            var id = (post["Post"]!["id"]! as! String).toInt()!
            var title = post["Post"]!["title"]! as String
            var author = post["Post"]!["author"]! as String
            var content = post["Post"]!["content"]! as String
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Link DB
    var postsCollection = [Post]()

    var service:PostService!

}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question could be easier to analyze if you could provide more details: at which line do you get the error? What kind of data does the `response["posts"]` contains, I assume it's an array of `NSDictionary`, is this correct? Could you update your question with these details, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyObject is not convertible to String.

You should let it knows post["Post"] is NSDictionary or what type you define it.

```
func loadPosts(posts:NSArray) {
    for post in posts {
        var id = ((post["Post"]! as? NSDictionary)!["id"]! as! String).toInt()!
        var title = (post["Post"]! as? NSDictionary)!["title"]! as String
        var author = (post["Post"]! as? NSDictionary)!["author"]! as String
        var content = (post["Post"]! as? NSDictionary)!["content"]! as String
    }
}
```

Comment: This is guaranteed to crash if any of the 4 keys is missing, or the corresponding value is not `String`.

Comment: Yap, cause it used ! instead of ?.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code, I will try to teach you how you can make it better so that you no longer receive the compile error, and you better handler various points of failure.

First things first, let's Swiftify your code and make use of the type system:

```
self.loadPosts(response["posts"]! as! NSArray)
```

can be better written as

```
if let postsDicts = response["posts"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    loadPosts(postsDicts)
} else {
    // the server response didn't send the proper "posts"
}
```

, the [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) allowing you to handle the scenario where the server sent an invalid response.

Secondly, let's specify `loadPosts` to accept an array of dictionaries (exactly the type to which we casted above):

```
func loadPosts(posts: [[String:AnyObject]])
```

And not lastly, all that forced unwraps (`!`) can make your app crash without thinking twice. The problem is that you can't control which data will the server send - a bug in a server can cause your application to crash if you blindly trust it's data, so you need to add safeguards to avoid app crashes due to invalid data:

```
func loadPosts(posts: [[String:AnyObject]]) {
    for post in posts {
        guard let postDetail = post["Post"] as? [String:AnyObject],
            id = postDetail["id"] as? String,
            title = postDetail["title"] as? String,
            author = postDetail["author"] as? String,
            content = postDetail["content"] as? String else {
            continue
        }
        // I assume here you would construct a Post object
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `NSArray` can be safely caster to a Swift array (e.g [String], or as in your case `[[String:AnyObject]]`, similarly a `NSDictionary` can be safely casted to a Swift dictionary. Working with Swift's data types give you more flexibility and can help you write less and more robust code.